# jQuery select only tr/td in main table, not nested tables

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html-table

html code

```
<table class="fruits" border="1">
<tr>
    <td>Apple</td>
    <td>$2.50</td>
    <td>
        <table>
            <tr><td>Nice</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Cheap</td></tr>
        </table>
    </td>
    <td>Buy Apple</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Pineapple</td>
    <td>$2.50</td>
    <td>
        <table>
            <tr><td>Nice</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Cheap</td></tr>
        </table>
    </td>
    <td>Buy Pineapple</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Watermelon</td>
    <td>$3.20</td>
    <td>
        <table>
            <tr><td>Nice</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Cheap</td></tr>
        </table>
    </td>
    <td>Buy Watermelon</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Orange</td>
    <td>$1.50</td>
    <td>
        <table>
            <tr><td>Nice</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Cheap</td></tr>
        </table>
    </td>
    <td>Buy Orange</td>
</tr>
```

jQuery

```
var table = $("table");
table.find('tr').each(function (i) {
    var $tds = $(this).find('td'),

    fruit = $tds.eq(0).text(),
    buy = $tds.eq(3).text()         

    alert(fruit +" "+ buy);     
});
```

I want click the button and select on item in column 1 and 4, but that is another nest table, so coding in jQuery give me the wrong information. Anyone can help me jQuery in below?

Comment: why don't you give ID / class ?

Answer (score 2):

The following approach is based of “positive thinking”: instead of excluding inner tables, we include just the outer table and the right elements:

```
$("table.fruits > tbody > tr")
.each(function (i) {
    var $tds = $(this).children('td'),
    fruit = $tds.eq(0).text(),
    buy = $tds.eq(3).text()         
    console.log(fruit +" "+ buy);     
});
```

If the table may contain `thead` elements, the code may need to be modified.

This simple version just selects all rows of the outer table (but not any row of any inner table) with the selector `table.fruits > tbody > tr`. In the DOM, `tr` elements do not appear as children of `table` but of `tbody` (or `thead`), even if no `<tbody>` markup is used.

When processing a row, it is best to use the `children()` method, which selects just the direct descendants (children).

Comment: Yeah, this is better than my answer using not().  I didn't know about the `<tbody>`.

Answer (score 0):

write class="f1" in all tr(you can check in html).working code is below.

```
<script>

    $(document).ready(function() {  
    var table = $("table.fruits"); 
    table.find('tr.f1').each(function (i) {  //this will find only tr which have class f1 not nested table . 
    var $tdsfirst = $(this).find('td:first');// find first td 
    var $tdslast = $(this).find('td:last');  //find last td
    fruit = $tdsfirst.text();
    buy = $tdslast.text();            

    alert(fruit +" "+ buy);     
}); 

  } ); 


   </script>  

<table class="fruits" border="1">
<tr class="f1">
    <td>Apple</td>
    <td>$2.50</td>
    <td>
        <table>
            <tr><td>Nice</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Cheap</td></tr>
        </table>
    </td>
    <td>Buy Apple</td>
</tr> 
<tr class="f1"> 
    <td>Pineapple</td>
    <td>$2.50</td>
    <td>
        <table>
            <tr><td>Nice</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Cheap</td></tr>
        </table>
    </td>
    <td>Buy Pineapple</td>
</tr>
<tr class="f1">
    <td>Watermelon</td>
    <td>$3.20</td>
    <td>
        <table>
            <tr><td>Nice</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Cheap</td></tr>
        </table>
    </td>
    <td>Buy Watermelon</td>
</tr> 
<tr class="f1">
    <td>Orange</td>
    <td>$1.50</td>
    <td>
        <table>
            <tr><td>Nice</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Cheap</td></tr>
        </table>
    </td>
    <td>Buy Orange</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution for you that does not require adding classes to the HTML.  It mostly relies on the `not()` selector.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kdNng/

```
$("table.fruits tr").not("table table tr").each(function ()
{
    var tds = $(this).children('td');

    var fruit = tds.eq(0).text();
    var buy = tds.eq(3).text();

    alert(fruit +" "+ buy);
});
```